# Git magic references

Tags: git

I'm playing around with project-workflows and Git and I'd like to figure out a nice way to "talk" to the main-repository.

One thing I'm wondering is how to realize a magical reference like the "for" used by Gerrit where commits are push to "refs/for/xxxx/topic" in order to set the final target branch without placing things directly there. Is there a way to do this with pre/post receive hooks our is that a special feature of their Java implementation?

Cheers

Comment: I suppose if you were really careful, you could write a post-receive hook which, given that `refs/for/X` was pushed to, updates a different ref (`refs/for-X-private/id-number` or whatever), then resets `refs/for/X` back to `X`. (Presumably anything for `X` is a fast-forward from `X`, so the `for` branch would need to be there to allow all possible pushes.) It's kinda sketchy though; it seems like there are a lot of potential pitfalls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`refs/for/branch` is a "magic" feature of the Gerrit git server. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to replicate it using the default `git-receive-pack` or `git-http-server` implementations.

Comment: To be a little more specific, I believe the Gerrit server lies a bit - it tells you you're interacting with `refs/for/branch`, while on the other side with the repository, it actually manipulates a different ref. This means that the native transport mechanisms don't support it, because they represent direct communication.

Answer (score 1):

As @duskwuff correctly pointed out, it's a "magic" feature of Gerrit and it achieves it by actually implementing a git server (via jgit).

However, it's possible to approximate it with a plain git repo and hooks. To do it cleanly we need two hooks:

1. `update` hook: do something special when you receive, including creating new refs
2. `post-receive` hook: just remove the ref created by update: `git update-ref -d ${refname}`

You could do all in `post-receive` hook if you don't care about the possibility of returning an error the the client.

The `post-receive` hook is necessary since the ref will be created after the `update` script returns successfully.

It even works if two users concurrently push. There might be a short race condition though while the ref is created but before the post-receive hook has deleted it, I never encountered this but I do expect it to happen from my superficial understanding of how git works. So this might not be a suitable solution when you have a heavy push traffic to this magic ref.

I use it to clone the repo in a temp dir and spawn docker image build. I encode the name of the image to build in the ref name. (I don't need to create a real ref like gerrit does, but it would be possible)